# Issues with Entity Framework - MySQL LinQ Queries

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am facing an issues while using ternary operator in where condition, along with group by clause in LinQ queries.

My application is MVC4 with Entity Framework 6(MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll version 6.9.6), connected to MySQL DB - 5.6.

A sample query listed here:

```
bool activeFlag = true;
var objCurrency = (from table in Db.Table.AsNoTracking()
       where (activeFlag ? table.Active == 1 : table.Active == 0)
       group table by table.Code into grp
       select grp.OrderByDescending(t =>table.EffectiveFrom). FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

The query is working fine with MS SQL 2008 R2, but failed on MySql.

The query is working if we remove either the ternary operator from where clause or if we remove the group by.

There are alternate methods to write the business logic but I have to re-write the code on lot of other places too. I am trying avoid the rework.

Please advice how to resolve this.. Is it a bug in EF MySQL provider.?